# Generate a list with random values between a and b

Tags: list-manipulation, export, random

I am trying to perform system identification.. To properly identify the system i have to give the system a "rich" signal which are able to "activate" all the modes of the plant.  A rich signal would therefore be a signal which would look something like white noise or a very noisy signal, where nothing can be predicted or hard at least to do.. 
Therefore i need Mathmatica to create a list of values that resembles a noisy signal from a to b, and could be nice to export to a csv file, so i won't have to manually insert them..

I tried program it my self but it seemed to predictable, and making it come a distribution isn't that good aswell.. so what is the most random way ..

Comment: see `RandomReal` or `RandomInteger` and `Export`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: What have you done in terms of checking the documentation?

Comment: It might help to be clearer on what you mean by noise in this instance.  Especially with your comment below.   A truly random noise wont identify anything, or are you intentionally trying to create a noisy signal from a clean one?  On stack exchange you are expected to spend time showing what you have tried so far and clearly structure your question.

Comment: changed.. hope it shines some light on my issue..

Comment: Do you mean you want to **add noise to a clean signal**? Or just generate a random walk? `ListLinePlot[Accumulate[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 100]]]`

Comment: Just generate a noise...  not add anything to anything..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generate a random signal, if that is indeed what you mean, using a random walk. For example, 1000 samples would look something like this:

```
(* Generate the samples and plot *)
samples = Accumulate[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 1000]];
ListLinePlot[samples]

(* And to export them to CSV *)
Export["\\path\\to\\file\\randomsamples.csv", samples, "CSV"];
```

[image]

And you can generate one according to a normal distribution too (this is what I understand "white noise" to mean), just by replacing `RandomReal` with the appropriate distribution (try and spot the difference!).

```
ListLinePlot[
   {
    Accumulate[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 1000]], 
    Accumulate[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 1000]]
   }, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Uniform", "Normal"}]
```

[image]

Comment: That's a simple and nifty way to generate a random walk. Nice! (+1)

Answer (score 5):

You need to ask yourself a few more questions about what you want.

- If you want your random numbers to be uniformly distributed in the $(a,b)$ interval, the easiest functions to use are [`RandomReal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomReal.html) to get real numbers, or [`RandomInteger`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomInteger.html) to get integer values. These functions are similar to the `RAND()` function in Excel or similar spreadsheets.
- [`RandomVariate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomVariate.html) is a more versatile version of those random number generators, in that it allows you to pick samples from a specific statistical distribution of your choice. You tell this function where to pick its samples by specifying a statistical distribution as one of its parameters. So depending on how you want your random numbers to be distributed in the interval $(a,b)$, consider:

  - [`UniformDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UniformDistribution.html) for values uniformly spread all over the interval; again, this combination is similar to the result of the `RAND()` function in Excel or similar spreadsheets.
  - [`NormalDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NormalDistribution.html) for samples distributed according to a Gaussian (i.e. normal) distribution, as many common sources of random noise are.

As an example, suppose that you want 10 real numbers picked from the interval $(20,30)$, and spread uniformly over that interval. You would then write:

```
samples = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{20, 30}], 10]
```

Now that we have stored those random numbers in the `samples` variable, we can **export them to a** `.CSV` **file** using the `Export` command:

```
Export[$UserDocumentsDirectory <> "\\randomsamples.csv", samples, "CSV"]
```

This will generate a file called `randomsamples.csv`, containing the random numbers we generated above as a comma-separated list, and place it in your Documents directory.

Comment: I try to recreate a noisy signal which can be used for system identification..

Comment: System identification is part of matlab (ident) and not part of the issue.. 
I only mentioned for the sake of context.

Comment: OK. Try running the sample code at the very bottom of my answer. You can change the `10` argument to change how many values you generate. I will add a point on the exporting the data as CSV as well.